# How do you call it when you use the { } brackets for displaying html content in php?

Tags: php

I encountered a problem where I need to separate the html content more than I already have. Right now I have so many includes but would like to reduce them in numbers. I read about php templating but that is somewhat too advanced for a starter since that is in OOP. Is there any procedural way of doing things?

The idea is too reduce the number of includes and have a nice seperation for html and php.

I already done a lot of work by creating a functions folder and a folder for my html. I am not 100% happy with the results. I did do enough nested includes (for example head+header creates the overall_header) but I want to optimize things further.

So what methods are there to clean things up? I prefer to do it myself instead of using libraries as it would be like driving a ferrari on top of a ferrari.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you don't want to use external libraries. Many of them provide simple integration (Twig / Smarty).

Comment: +1 for smarty. I was about to recommend it until I read that you dont want external libraries. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @LukášRutar because I want to understand how it works under the hood and I simply want to be a better developer

Comment: @MichaëlGarrez I want to push the boundaries and understand how those things work. Using external libraries would be overkill. I mean especially in php I think

Comment: I don't think being a better developer means reinvent the wheel but if that's what you want you can always check those libraries (not use it) to understand how they work. They all share common principles with various implementations. Feel free to check those source codes.

Comment: @MichaëlGarrez I agree but for a starter like me I think it is better that I dont get used to using libraries

Comment: How does the title of your question in any way relate to the content of your question?

Answer (score -2):

It is known as blade templating

Comment: Laravel is somewhat a standard like jquery. Looks interesting but I was thinking of creating my own minimal templating system for only html elements.

Comment: Laravel is a php framework. jQuery is a javascript library. The two are totally different things.
Coming to your question, There are a lot of templating libraries available out there. Reinventing the wheel may cause a lot of complications and your custom made library may or may not even work. I would suggest to go with some existing library and focus on the core implementation of your project rather that creating your own templating system.